# reactjs - creating random shapes, colors and range of sizes of material ui icons for a drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a drag and drop application -- and I want to do something interesting with the idol state near the cloud icon.

I want to define a set of material icons I can render, and an array of colors they can be and sizes. On componentDidMount -- create a random number of items - which could be random shapes, sizes and colors.

I am unsure how to loop through these and apply the random states and properties

latest codebase

- https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-feather-rrl76

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import CloudQueueIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CloudQueue";

import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUncheckedOutlined";
import FiberManualRecordIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FiberManualRecord";

import "./MagicCloud.scss";

class MagicCloud extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      icons: [
        <AddIcon />,
        <RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon />,
        <FiberManualRecordIcon />
      ],
      colors: ["red", "blue", "pink"]
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getShapes();
  }

  getRandomArrayEl(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

  shapeMaker() {
    const randomShape = this.getRandomArrayEl(this.state.icons);
    console.log("randomShape", randomShape);
    return randomShape;
  }

  getShapes() {
    let randomSize = 10;

    let items = [];
    let that = this;

    for (let i = 0; i < randomSize; i++) {
      //items.push(this.shapeMaker("x", "x", "x"))

      items.push(<AddIcon />);
      //items.push(this.shapeMaker());
    }

    //console.log("items", items);

    this.setState({ items: items });

    //return {items[0]}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="magic-cloud">
        <div className="lucky-cloud-container">
          <CloudQueueIcon className="cloud" />
          <div>Drag and drop to upload</div>
          <div class="lucky-charms">
            {this.state.items &&
              this.state.items.map(function (item) {
                {
                  item;
                }
              })}
          </div>
        </div>

        {/*
        <AddIcon className="small gold bubble x1" />
        <RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon className="small pink bubble x2" />
        <FiberManualRecordIcon className="small purple bubble x3" />

        <AddIcon className="small purple bubble x1" />
        <RadioButtonUncheckedOutlinedIcon className="small lavendar bubble x2" />
        <FiberManualRecordIcon className="small gold bubble x3" />
        */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MagicCloud;
```

Comment: current sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-feynman-hvci2

Comment: got this close - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-aryabhata-pfz1u

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-feather-rrl76